# Met problem while installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation

I prepared the USB boosting disk from the tutorial first, after restarted my computer, it leads me to the Boot Menu.

Now I have two options here, one is `TOSHIBA TransMemory (14891MB)` and the other is `UEF1: (FAT) TOSHIBA TransMemory (14891MB)`, I believe that either of these options could lead me to the installation but with difference of the UI interface and the grub menu.

However as I tried the first one, after some purple screen and a Ubuntu logo, my monitor failed to display anything and “Input signal out of range” is shown. It really troubles me and I really don't know where to solve the problem.

My second option lead me to a black interface, with options `*Try Ubuntu without installing`, `Install Ubuntu`, `OEM install (for manufactures)` and `Check disc for defects`, I tried these four and what I get is a black screen, I realized that `nomodeset` should be set somewhere but how? I can get access to the `grub>` by the way, and I can also edit a file with command `e`, but after then I really don't know what to do.

BTW, I am using GTX 1070 as graphic card, is that the reason I got `input signal out of range` error shown on my monitor?